# Can I use a belongsTo method with name 'asset'?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model "SalesContract" which has a "belongsTo" relationship with a class called "Asset". However, it does not work (I cannot set or get).

Could it be an issue with the "asset()" helper method?

If I change the name of my method to something like "related_asset()", then it works.

This does NOT work:

```
public function asset()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class);
}
```

This DOES work:

```
public function related_asset()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class);
}
```

Full model:

```
class SalesContract extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Commentable;

    const icon_class = 'far fa-file-signature';

    const default_buyer_fee = 100;
    const default_carproof_fee = 36.45;

    protected $fillable = [
        'number', 'asset_id', 'seller_id', 'buyer_id', 'buyer_representative', 'sale_date', 'sale_price',
        'apply_sales_taxes_to_sale_price', 'buyer_fee', 'carproof_fee', 'deposit'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'sale_date' => 'datetime',
        'sale_price' => 'float',
        'carproof_fee' => 'float',
        'buyer_fee' => 'float',
        'deposit' => 'float',
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
        'deleted_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'subtotal', 'taxable_amount', 'sales_taxes', 'total', 'balance'
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        });

        static::saving(function($table) {
            if (empty($table->id)) {
                if ($current_user = Auth::user()) {
                    $table->created_by_user_id = $current_user->id;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        if (empty($this->sale_date)) {
            $this->sale_date = Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        if (empty($this->id)) {
            if (empty($this->number)) {
                if ($asset = $this->asset) {
                    $this->number = $asset->external_file_number ?? $asset->internal_file_number;
                }
            }
            $this->buyer_fee = $this->buyer_fee ?? self::default_buyer_fee;
            $this->carproof_fee = $this->carproof_fee ?? self::default_carproof_fee;
            $this->apply_sales_taxes_to_sale_price = $this->apply_sales_taxes_to_sale_price ?? 1;
        }

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return __('sales_contracts.item_label', ['number' => $this->number ?? $this->id]);
    }

    public function scopeFilter($query, $filters)
    {
        $filters = is_array($filters) ? array_filter($filters) : [];
        return $query->where($filters);
    }

    public function asset()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class);
    }

    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
    }

    public function created_by_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function getSubtotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->sale_price + $this->carproof_fee + $this->buyer_fee;
    }

    public function getTaxableAmountAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->apply_sales_taxes_to_sale_price) {
            return $this->subtotal;
        } else {
            return $this->subtotal - $this->sale_price;
        }
    }

    public function getSalesTaxesAttribute()
    {
        $sales_taxes = [];
        if ($seller = $this->seller) {
            foreach ($seller->sales_tax_numbers as $tax_number) {
                if ($tax_number->use) {
                    if ($sales_tax = $tax_number->sales_tax) {
                        $sales_taxes[] = [
                            'sales_tax' => $sales_tax,
                            'name' => $sales_tax->name,
                            'rate' => $sales_tax->rate,
                            'label' => $sales_tax->label,
                            'number' => $tax_number->number,
                            'amount' => round($this->taxable_amount * $sales_tax->rate, 2)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $sales_taxes;
    }

    public function getSalesTaxesTotalAttribute()
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->sales_taxes as $sales_tax) {
            $total += $sales_tax['amount'];
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->subtotal + $this->sales_taxes_total;
    }

    public function getBalanceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->total - $this->deposit;
    }
}
```

From controller:

```
$sales_contract = new SalesContract;

if ($request->has('sales_contract')) {
    $sales_contract->fill($request->input('sales_contract'));
}
```

Result of `dd($request->input())`:

```
array:1 [▼
  "sales_contract" => array:1 [▼
    "asset_id" => "11754"
  ]
]
```

(Yes, Asset with ID 11754 does exist.)

Comment: How are you using the relationship? `asset` is collision proof as far as I can tell.

Comment: public function asset()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Asset', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}

Comment: I will use the $request->input() to fill the model. I can then access the attribute $contract->asset_id but $contract->asset returns NULL. And yes, I added 'asset_id' to the fillable attributes.

Comment: protected $table = 'table_name'; in Asset model also if the id name of assets table is not id like asset_id you should     protected $primaryKey = 'asset_id';

Comment: Does the `contracts` table have a column named `asset`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, yes it does have the column.

Comment: @AhmedAboud, everything is set to standards. Asset table is assets and pk is id.

Comment: A column and a relationship can't have the same name.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, sorry, I mean it has a column called 'asset_id'.

Comment: Please post the whole `Contract` model.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, ok just posted the whole model. Also, I figured that if I set the `asset_id` value directly and not through `fill`, it works.

Comment: Please post the code that uses `fill()`. What's the result of `dd($request->input());`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, small precision: this works: `$sales_contract->asset = Asset::find($request->input('sales_contract.asset_id'))` but not this `$sales_contract->asset_id = Asset::find($request->input('sales_contract.asset_id'))->id`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, I added requested code to the original question.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($request->input('sales_contract'));`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, it's what you would expect: `array:1 [▼
  "asset_id" => "11754"
]`

Comment: Is the `fill()` line executed? What's the result of `dd($sales_contract->getAttributes());` in the end?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, yes it does run. Here is the dd: `array:5 [▼
  "sale_date" => "2019-06-02 00:00:00"
  "buyer_fee" => 100
  "carproof_fee" => 36.45
  "apply_sales_taxes_to_sale_price" => 1
  "asset_id" => "11754"
]`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, I don't understand why this makes it work: `$sales_contract->asset = Asset::find($request->input('sales_contract.asset_id'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194341/discussion-between-jonathan-roy-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Answer (score 0):

by default Name of relation is depended on 'foreign_key'

if you want to set different name of relation than foreign key just provide foreign key and other_key along with relation declaration

```
public function asset()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class,related_asset,id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I had to remove the following code from my `__construct()` method as it was breaking the relationship somehow:

```
if (empty($this->number)) {
    if ($asset = $this->asset) {
        $this->number = $asset->external_file_number ?? $asset->internal_file_number;
    }
}
```